# No consigo obtener el nombre del usuario Facebook api js

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-api

Tengo este código para probar el conseguir el nombre del usuario

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
});
```

pero la respuesta que me da la consola es:

> Successful login for: undefined

sin el .name la respuesta es:

> Successful login for: [object Object]

es decir me retorna el response.name como undefined... ya tengo comprobado que el usuario este conectado y todo pero no conseguí obtener su información básica, había otra forma que me pedía un token que no se conseguir pero de todas maneras este método debería funcionar por que es el mismo ejemplo que me entrega la documentación de la api de Facebook.

Comment: Haber dale sin el `name` vamos viendo que te arroja todo el response.. Pones el resultado

Comment: @AlfonsoCarrasco Dice:
`Successful login for: [object Object]`

Comment: ok Itera el object; ` console.log(typeof response); //solo quiero estar seguro que es un object
 for(var a in response){ console.log(a,response[a]); }` con esto veremos que indices y valores trae tu response... agrega lo que te arroje

Comment: @AlfonsoCarrasco An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

Bien creo que al final si tendre que usar el toke, resulta que como la documentación aparece así crei que podría usarlo ademas que puedo usar response.status sin el token gracias por ayudarme a encontrar el error

Comment: Si le quitaste el comentario que deje de:  //solo quiero estar seguro que es un object

Comment: Más simple pon en el consolé log JSON.strignify(response) para ver la estructura

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,email,permissions', function(response) {
    console.log('Bienvenido, ' + response.name + '.');
    alert('Bienvenido, ' + response.name + '.');
});
```

Referencia y para más información:

[FB - Public Profile](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-public_profile)

[Graph API User](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user)

Comment: me aparece undefined de todas formas

Comment: Tienes que estar seguro que el usuario este logueado y de la autorización a tu aplicación antes de usar la API... para más información: [Quickstart](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart)